# JSerial - cannot read data from serial port

Tags: java

Currently, I am working with [JSerial](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki) library to write/read data to/from micro-controller. This `[0x00AA550A]` checks for battery level and should return `[0х00AA5502XXYYYY]` `XX` is percentage in hex.

Here I write data:

```
SerialPort port = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[0];
port.openPort();
try {
     byte[] b = new byte[]{ (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x0A };

     int writter = port.writeBytes(b, b.length);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And below I read data from microcontroller as a result:

```
port.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
            @Override
            public int getListeningEvents() { return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE; }
            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE)
                    return;
                byte[] newData = new byte[port.bytesAvailable()];
                int numRead = port.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
                System.out.println("Read " + numRead + " bytes.");
            }
        });
```

But the result is not showing. Empty console. Could you, please, tell me what is wrong with my code, and it would be better to suggest better suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't init your serial port then that maybe the reason.
Please setting these value according to your env.

```
 port.setBaudRate(9600);
 port.setNumDataBits(8);
 port.setNumStopBits(1);
 port.setParity(0);
 port.setFlowControl(0);
```

Or you have more Console Port with your PC, the `[0]` is not the right console port 
you wish to connected.

Here I just post the code that working for me.

```
  private void connect() {
    String str = (String) model.getElementAt(boxSerial.getSelectedIndex());
    SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

    SerialPort port = null;
    for (SerialPort porta : ports) {
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(porta.getDescriptivePortName())) {
            port = porta;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (port != null) {
        port.setBaudRate(9600);
        port.setNumDataBits(8);
        port.setNumStopBits(1);
        port.setParity(0);
        port.setFlowControl(0);


        port.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
            @Override
            public int getListeningEvents() {
                return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
            }

            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {


                if (serialPortEvent.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE){
                    System.out.println("  event_type="+serialPortEvent.getEventType());
                    return;
                }


                try {
                    int len = serialPortEvent.getSerialPort().bytesAvailable();

                    byte data[] = new byte[len];
                    serialPortEvent.getSerialPort().readBytes(data, len);

                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        byte b = data[i];
                        System.out.print(String.format("%02x ",b));
                    }                       
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        boolean b = port.openPort();
        if (!b) {
            port.closePort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, when debugging, I checked all the data was already init-ed for me. And for the 2nd case u mentioned, data at ind 0 is not null

Comment: Then you need to check your hardware connection, using an Oscilloscope to check if the Tx/Rx signal is OK.

Comment: connection is set

Comment: If the hardware connection is OK, then my guess your problem is the [0], please print out the name of this serial port.

Comment: And the setBaudRate is 9600 or 115200?